# making a matrix with for loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix

I am very new to C, so my question may seem very preliminary, sorry for that! I want to make a 2-dimensional matrix in C with N rows (in the code below N = 100) and 1 column, by multiplying a constant amount to every element (based on its index) for making the next element. This is the code I try but it doesn't work:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
float a[100];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    a[i] = 3.08e-7+(i-1)*0.9e-7;
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

I willl be really grateful if someone can give me a hint.

Comment: What do you mean with 'doesn't work'?

Comment: What does not work?  Can you be more specific?  By the way, if you want to print a `float`, you should use `%f` in your `printf()`.

Comment: Try this: `printf("%f\n", a[i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you don't want to multiply by -1 on the first iteration of the loop. Try the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
float a[100];
int i;

for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    a[i-1] = 3.08e-7 + i * 0.9e-7;
    printf("%f\n", a[i-1]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, it's working now :) but when I run this, why it shows me just 28 elements of my matrix in the console? and not all of them?

Comment: Because your window is too small?

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong format specifier. Use `%f` instead of `%d` (d is only for printing integer values).

Comment: Are you sure `%d` doesn't stand for "decimal"? Not that that makes much more sense than "digit", of course ...

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%f\n", a[i]);
```

Even if you have a floating value in `a[i]` your are printing a integer value of it which is not what you want, use `%f` to print float.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to change is the printf statement. You're using the wrong 'placeholder'. Also i would add `.10` so you see more from your number:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    double a[100];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        a[i] = 3.08e-7+(i-1)*0.9e-7;
        printf("%.10lf\n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```